# Multiple Bootstrap DateTimepicker values in single text box

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the [bootstrap datetime picker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) and I want to add time values in a single text box, like this:

```
09:30-12:00,18:00-23:00,09:30-12:00,18:00-23:00
```

Is this possible? If so, can anyone help me.

Comment: why would you like to do that? What have you tried? You can use a second input field to populate the selected times from your picker

Comment: I want to user to given a multiple to-from times in single text box I found something similar with date
http://jsfiddle.net/51cfb3sg/
but I want to add times like 09:30-12:00,18:00-23:00

Comment: And you can't use that?

Comment: its a datepicker , I want use same datetimepicker that I am already using (http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) and only time values